# Typescript: Is there a way to change the type depending on the value of an attribute?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm trying to change the type of the object depending on the value of the "key" attribute.

I have some types like `AElement`,`BElement`,...,`ZElement`. Each element has a common attribute called "name". So depends on that attribute the type must be changed.

For example:

```js
// Elements
type AElement = {name:"a"; propA: string;}
type BElement = {name:"b"; propB: number;}
type CElement = {name:"c"; propC: string;}
// ...
type ZElement = {name:"z"; propZ: string; propZZ: number;}

// Map interface
interface ElementsMap {
    "a": AElement;
    "b": BElement;
    "c": CElement;
    //...
    "z": ZElement
}

// My custom type
type Elem<K extends keyof ElementsMap = keyof ElementsMap> = ElementsMap[K];

// Use it
let elements:Elem[] = [{
    name: "a",
    propA: "123",
},{
    name: "c",
    propC: "321",
},{
    name: "z",
    propZ: "123",
    propZZ: 123,
}];

// Test
let test1 = elements[2];
let test2: Elem = {
    name: "a",
    propA: "123",
}
```

I expect when I use `Element[]` each type depends on the key attribute "name" I can use the different props of the type. But the type of the variables of test1 and test2 is: `AElement | BElement | CElement | ZElement` for each one, but I expect `ZElement` and `AElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a underlying 'feature' of "Arrays" and is working as intended, indexing an array at a particular index will always yield that Arrays type even if that type is a union.

It will also always yield the Arrays type regardless of what value is at that index,

Only tuples can be indexed at a key to receive the type at that key and that's because they have a length known at runtime where-as Arrays do not.

Take the following code as an example.

```
const testTuple: [AElement, CElement, ZElement] = [{
    name: "a",
    propA: "123",
},{
    name: "c",
    propC: "321",
},{
    name: "z",
    propZ: "123",
    propZZ: 123,
}];
const TestTypeAtIndex = testTuple[0] // AElement and not a union.
```

There are many workarounds for this leave a comment if you want to know more, but i would say the easiest is just to add a user-defined typeguard, the more complicated work-arounds provide a better quality of life with a more complicated implementation.

```
// use it as array.
const testTuple: Elem[] = [{
    name: "a",
    propA: "123",
},{
    name: "c",
    propC: "321",
},{
    name: "z",
    propZ: "123",
    propZZ: 123,
}];

const isAElement = (ele: ElementsMap[keyof ElementsMap]): ele is AElement => {
    return "propA" in ele;
}

const testTypeAtIndex = testTuple[0] // union of everything
if(isAElement(testTypeAtIndex)) {
    const newTestType = testTypeAtIndex; // inside here its JUST AElement because of typeguard.
}
```